# Input class for GetVT function in behavioral change point analyses (bcpa)?

Tags: r, gps

I'm having a difficult time in correctly formatting objects for input in the GetVT function for behavioral point change analyses for a GPS collared animal. Please see code below:

```
Note:
st1269.trial$T = Time of fix
st1269.trial$X = X coordinate of fix
st1269.trial$Y= Y coordinate of fix

> st1269.trial = read.csv(file="collar_1269.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")

> head(st1269.trial)

             T        X         Y
1 2/8/2014 0:00 36.88826 0.4486350
2 2/8/2014 1:00 36.89338 0.4434400
3 2/8/2014 2:00 36.89337 0.4434450
4 2/8/2014 3:01 36.88977 0.4376533
5 2/8/2014 4:00 36.89083 0.4388550
6 2/8/2014 5:00 36.88649 0.4332834

> st1269.trial$T = as.numeric(st1269.trial$T)

> head(st1269.trial)

           T        X         Y
1 1391806800 36.88826 0.4486350
2 1391810400 36.89338 0.4434400
3 1391814000 36.89337 0.4434450
4 1391817660 36.88977 0.4376533
5 1391821200 36.89083 0.4388550
6 1391824800 36.88649 0.4332834

> GetVT(st1269.trial)
Error in data.frame(Z.start, Z.end, S, Phi, Theta, T.start, T.end, T.mid,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 506, 0
```

Alternatively, I have tried the following variations on the GetVT input

```
> GetVT(st1269.trial[c("T", "X", "Y")])
Error in data.frame(Z.start, Z.end, S, Phi, Theta, T.start, T.end, T.mid,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 506, 0

> GetVT(st1269.trial[c(1,2,3)])
Error in data.frame(Z.start, Z.end, S, Phi, Theta, T.start, T.end, T.mid,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 506, 0
```

Documentation within the Package 'bcpa' vignette suggests the appropriate input for the GetVT function is an object of class 'track', which is a dataframe with the columns X,Y and T. I experimented with different methods to coerce my object to class 'track' but to no avail. This must be a terribly simple solution, but it is evading my sincerest efforts. Any thoughts or suggestions on the best course forward?

Cordially,
M
Kenya

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as declaring:

```
class(st1269.trial) <- "track"
```

The package should also work if you change your time variable to a POSIX:

```
as.POSIXlt(st1269.trial$T, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%S")
```

The newest version of bcpa also has a convenient "MakeTrack" function, so that:

```
mytrack <- with(st1269.trial, MakeTrack(X, Y, T))
```

Will work.  Then, GetVT will work:

```
> GetVT(mytrack)
            Z.start             Z.end            S        Phi     Theta
2 36.89338+0.44344i 36.89337+0.44344i 1.118034e-05  2.6779450  3.470614
3 36.89337+0.44344i 36.88977+0.43765i 6.819369e-03 -2.1269319 -4.804877
4 36.88977+0.43765i 36.89083+0.43885i 1.602399e-03  0.8479684  2.974900
5 36.89083+0.43885i 36.88649+0.43328i 7.062459e-03 -2.2325697 -3.080538
   T.start    T.end    T.mid        dT            V             T.POSIX
2 1.000000 2.000000 1.500000 1.0000000 1.118034e-05 2014-02-08 01:30:00
3 2.000000 3.000278 2.500139 1.0002778 6.817475e-03 2014-02-08 02:30:00
4 3.000278 4.000000 3.500139 0.9997222 1.602844e-03 2014-02-08 03:30:00
5 4.000000 5.000000 4.500000 1.0000000 7.062459e-03 2014-02-08 04:30:00
```

If you are having more problems, feel free to contact the maintainer of the package (which is me), but not via stackoverflow.